# Vue element-ui <el-table-column> formatter – how to add new line/line break?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, newline, special-characters, element-ui

In Vue el-table-column I need to add new line or line break in order to display a list in one raw.
e.g:  In one cell: line1
line2
line3

Example code:

```js
 <el-table
   :data="tenancy.renewals"
   stripe
   height="300"
   style="width: 100%">

   <el-table-column
     prop="term"
     label="Term"
     :formatter="formatterNewLine"
     width="180">
   </el-table-column>
 </el-table>
```

in formatterNewLine if I add just '/n' or 
 it is not working as in view encoding the special characters.

Can anyone help on this for me?

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to put the additional line information in a different field?  Or, if there are many lines, can you add `<br>` where necessary?  If so, which do you prefer?

Comment: Why not using slots instead? This is way more flexible then a formatter